# How to install anything on CoreOS?

Tags: software-installation, coreos

I am running CoreOS 835.13.0.

This is the kind of problems I've ran into:

- `man` - `man: command not found`
- `info` - `info: command not found`
- `head -z a.txt` - `head: invalid option -- 'z'`
- `apt-get update` - `apt-get: command not found`

This is frustrating, so I'd like to install a few things to make my life easier.

Sadly, it seems that I simply can't install anything either.

- I've found [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreos-dev/FHBdG9B9SAg) on Google Groups but there is no solid answer.
- I've found [Is there any way to install Nano on CoreOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203606/is-there-any-way-to-install-nano-on-coreos) which shows a complex workaround that is specific to nano, so that doesn't help me.

How can I install things on CoreOS? Or better, how can I install `apt-get` in CoreOS (so that I can install anything else afterwards)?

Comment: CoreOS is designed to be bare-bones and thus contain just enough functionality to provide a clustering infrastructure, and nothing more. There's no package manager since there shouldn't be a need to install anything; Applications run in containers. Why is it that you need to install additional software on CoreOS?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa - I see. I wanted this because I wanted to set up a cron job executing a script which needed `head -z` among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreOS is designed to be bare-bones and thus contain just enough functionality to provide a clustering infrastructure, and nothing more. There's no package manager since there shouldn't be a need to install anything; Applications and/or services run in containers.

Since you want to execute a cron job, what you can do is use CoreOS to create either a [Docker](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/getting-started-with-docker.html) or [rkt](https://coreos.com/rkt/docs/latest/getting-started-guide.html) container within which you can install cron and run your job.

For example, you can create a Docker container using the Debian image and then use `apt-get` to install cron. The catch is that Docker containers are designed to run a process directly and typically don't have an init system, so you may have to start the cron daemon explicitly.